# Does parallel Ricci tensor imply constant scalar curvature?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Is that true that if a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ has parallel Ricci tensor i. e., $\nabla Ric=0$, then the manifold has constant scalar curvature?

I've seen this result with some aditional hypothesis and I'd like to know if it is true in this case as well, if it is a open problem or if there is some counter-example.

Comment: $scal = \mathrm{tr} Ric$ and $\nabla \mathrm{tr} = \mathrm{tr} \nabla$.

Comment: Sure; scalar curvature is the trace of $Ric$, so it's also parallel and thus constant.

Comment: Thank you Alexander and user8268, what I've seen is another notion of parallelism.

Comment: what does $\nabla\text{Ric}=0$ mean?