# parallel curvature imply constant Ricci and scalar curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

$\text{Suppose we have} \nabla R = 0 $, where R represents curvature tensor, Prove that Ricci  curvature and scalar curvature are constant.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I write down the condition in component， I have on ideal how to tansform the covariant derivative？ the scalar curvature is easy since I could calculate the derivation and it is zero, and I got the conclusion, but for Ricci ,it doesn't work.

Comment: The big picture is, $R$ is constant, hence so are its contractions. In detail: the covariant derivative fulfills the product rule of differentiation, and $g_{ij|k}=0$. This should get you further if you insist on looking at components.

Comment: I will have a try at first, thank you.

Comment: Does $Ric_{ij|h} = 0$ means $Ric = 0$？ can you prove it?

Comment: $\operatorname{Ric}_{ij|h}=0$ colloquially means that the Ricci tensor is constant (which is to be shown, as the question asks).

Comment: Wait, it seems I have led you from the right track here. The covariant derivative being zero is generally called *parallel*, not *constant*. You can (supposedly) figure out that the covariant derivatives vanish, but you cannot conclude *constant* from *parallel*?

Comment: @ccorn: For scalar functions parallel and constant are equivalent, while for other tensors there is no real notion of "constant" other than parallel - I'm guessing the question meant to say "Ricci curvature is parallel".

Comment: yes， my problem is  I cannot conclude constant from parallel, but the problem says clearly "constant"?

Comment: What does $\nabla R$ mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am assuming a
[Riemannian manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_manifold),
and I am going to use its
[Levi-Civita connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_connection).

Contrary to my initial assumption, the *constant* in the problem statement
is *not* just supposed to mean that the covariant derivative vanishes.
And you already know that [covariant differentiation and contraction commute](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493466).
I apologize for having used such a simple-minded interpretation
in the comments.

To fix the wording, a tensor field with vanishing covariant derivative
is called *parallel* here, not *constant*.
In fact, as Ted Shifrin has pointed out, any 
[locally Riemannian symmetric space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_space#Basic_properties)
features a *parallel* Riemann curvature tensor field,
but this does not make it a space of *constant curvature*.

We only require a *parallel* Riemann curvature tensor field,
but seek to establish a *constant* Ricci tensor field
and a constant scalar curvature. The latter is no problem,
as for scalar fields, *parallel* is still the same as *constant*.

For the Ricci tensor field, interpreted as a family of bilinear forms,
being *constant* in the strong sense means
$$\exists\lambda\in\mathbb{R}: \forall p\in M:
\forall X\in \operatorname{T}_p M:
\operatorname{Ric}(X,X) = \lambda\langle X,X\rangle$$
That property characterizes
an [Einstein manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_manifold).

So you are essentially asking whether every
locally Riemannian symmetric space is an Einstein manifold.
The answer is: **No**, but you seem to be close.

An easy counterexample to the proposition in question is
$$M = S\times T\quad\text{where}\quad S=\mathbb{S}^2,\ T = \mathbb{R}$$
the Riemannian product of the unit sphere $S$ and a line $T$.

For $p\in M$, decompose $p=(s,t)$ where $s\in S$, $t\in T$.
Likewise in the tangent space, the composition of $M$ allows you to
assemble $X\in \operatorname{T}_p M$ as $X=(X_s,X_t)$
where $X_s\in \operatorname{T}_s S$ and $X_t\in \operatorname{T}_t T$.
Furthermore, both $(X_s,0)$ and $(0,X_t)$ are in $\operatorname{T}_p M$,
and we have
$$\left\langle(X_s,X_t),(X_s,X_t)\right\rangle_p =
\langle X_s,X_s\rangle_s + \langle X_t,X_t\rangle_t$$
where the inner products are those of $\operatorname{T}_p M$,
$\operatorname{T}_s S$ and $\operatorname{T}_t T$ as indicated.

If you go through the calculations, you will find that
$$\begin{align}
\nabla R &= 0
\\ \operatorname{Ric}\left((X_s,0),(X_s,0)\right) &=
   \left\langle(X_s,0),(X_s,0)\right\rangle_p
   \neq 0 &\text{for }& X_s\neq 0
\\ \operatorname{Ric}\left((0,X_t),(0,X_t)\right) &=
   0 \neq \left\langle(0,X_t),(0,X_t)\right\rangle_p
   &\text{for }& X_t\neq 0
\end{align}$$
which shows that $M$ is locally symmetric, but not an Einstein manifold.

Now you might suspect that the statement of your question was only a near miss,
and you might want to additionally require some sort of
*irreducibility* of the Riemannian manifold $M$.
You may also want to require that $M$ be complete and simply connected
to get a global symmetric space from the local one.
Then look up e.g. the following:

1. Chapter XI (symmetric spaces), theorem 8.6 + corollary 8.7 from: Shoshichi Kobayashi and Katsumi Nomizu: Foundations of differential geometry, Vol.2. Wiley 1969
2. Section 2, corollary 3 from these [Lecture notes on symmetric spaces by J.-H. Eschenburg](http://www.math.uni-augsburg.de/%7Eeschenbu/symspace.pdf)

These concretize what *irreducibility* of $M$ shall mean and ultimately
establish an Einstein manifold.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is very specific.